Oauth2. How does server understand 'state' is belonging to a valid public client?
I am trying to understand how exactly state benefits Oauth flow by preventing CSRF. I just don't understand what the client server is comparing the state in the URL to. I have seen such an example:
Alice, good.com - good. Mallory, bad.com - bad. google.com - auth server. Alice is already authorized in good.com via google.com

Mallory begins an auth session.
good.com generates state=xyz, stores it in it's db and redirects Mallory to goodle.com/auth
Mallory completes a flow and 'traps' return URL with an auth code and state
Mallory gives this URL to Alice and she follows it. good.com is called like good.com/complete-auth?code=abc&state=xyz

So how exactly good.com can validate that the state=xyz is not belonging to Alice's browser? As I understand, to make it work, backend must, somehow, securely give the Alice's browser any sort of ID before the whole process begins. So when complete-auth is called that ID is also transferred. But it looks like it's only possible via cookies. This is the only way server can tell the browser during redirect to save something. I can't believe in it. How does mobile apps deal with that than?

Mobile apps use PKCE to protect against CSRF.

@HeikoTheißen PKCE kiks in when it comes to a public client to obtain credentials (i.e. JWT) from server. It happens after 'complete-auth' callback is called. So before completing the authorization resource server still needs to validate state is legit

I have found the real reason. For this entire OAuth flow to correctly happen the public client must be the first actor in the chain of OAuth flow. In other words it must start the flow, not the backend. By doing so, client generates a state on it's side and stores it whenever it's needed (for angular-oauth2-oidc it's local storage).
